# Reverse for 'xyz' not found. 'xyz' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have defined a function in my views.py

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse

def ax(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        *** Some code ***
    else:
        *** Some code ***
        return render(request, 'ajmytable2.html', context)
```

And this is my html

**ajmytable2.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}

    ** Some code **

<script type="text/javascript">
      ** Some Code **
  $(document).on('submit','#my_form',function data(){
    var dataGrid = $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid("instance");
    var selectedKeys = dataGrid.getSelectedRowKeys();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url 'ax' %}',
          ** Some Code **
          }
       });
});
</script>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from dash.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    ** Some url patterns**,
    path('ax/', ax, name='ax'),
]
```

But when I run my server with the url "ax/", I am getting an error like "Reverse for 'mytable1' not found. 'mytable1' is not a valid view function or pattern name." I don't have a view named mytable1. But I am unable to find from where this error is coming. I  am attaching a screenshot of the error image also. Please help me to sort out this.

Thanks
[image: screenshot]

Comment: please post the full stacktrace

Comment: @ruddra Pls have a look at the new screenshot

Comment: what is `base.html` source code? And what is the content of 'some code'?

Comment: try using this url: '{% url "ax" %}'. Also have you configured your django settings properly. ?

Comment: So show the code attempting to reverse `mytable1`. And please stop posting screenshots of text - use text.